# Anylogic - Change direction of the path during runtime

Tags: anylogic

is it possible to change the direction of the path in the PaletteRack during the simulation run ?

Background : we have special aisles (PaletteRack) in our warehouse simulation, where we want to allow transporters to enter only from one direction - e.g. block the entrance from the opposite direction and after the transporter leave the aisle unblock that entrance again

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the direction of path in runtime unfortunately. Path network (incl. all paths directions) is kind of a rigid thing that is not modifiable  after model start. But there is a workaround -  use two restricted areas on both ends of the aisle. To implement the rules for entering those areas will require a bit of coding. Short example: area1 should be open for all transporters (if its the end from which entrance is allowed), but  area2 should only allow entrance for those transporters which are already inside the aisle.